# How do I apply 3D convolution to my data?

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0GCl.png) I have a 3D array with a size of (1000, 7, 7), and I want to use 44 convolutional filters, each having dimensions of (5, 5). After convolution, I expect the result to be in the shape of (1000, 44, 3, 3).

I've written the following code, but I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, BatchNormalization, Reshape

def convolution_block(input_tensor):
    # First Conv3D layer with (5,5) kernels, 44 filters, and stride of 1
    conv1 = Conv3D(filters=44, kernel_size=(5, 5, 1), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='valid')(input_tensor)
    # Second Conv3D layer with (3,3) kernels, 44 filters, and stride of 1
    conv2 = Conv3D(filters=44, kernel_size=(3, 3, 1), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='valid')(conv1)
    conv3= Conv3D(filters=44, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='valid')(conv2)
    batch_norm = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    
    resized_output = Reshape(target_shape=(1000, 44))(batch_norm)
    
    return resized_output

    

# Example usage
input_shape = (7, 7, 1000,1)  # Example input shape (TP, C, H, W)

input_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
conv_block_output = convolution_block(input_tensor)

# Create a model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=conv_block_output)

# Print model summary
model.summary()
```

I want to use 44 convolutional filters, each having dimensions of (5, 5). After convolution, I expect the result to be in the shape of (1000, 44, 3, 3).

I've written the following code, but I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

Comment: What tensor output did you get?  Did you run it and get the shape you think you want?  If yes, why do you think this is the correct result?  If not, what should you change to correct it?

Comment: Could you share your dataset, so that I can try it?

Comment: @duffymo actually am trying to follow this article [ https://doi.org/10.3390/brainsci13020268 ]to get same output for each layer ,you can check the image which i attached .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1000 stands for 1000 samples, you don't give this to the input shape of the model. The input shape should be for one image only. For training, a model is given batches of data, and this is the `(None,` in the shapes in your image.
Also, TensorFlow expects the image shape in the order (Height, Width, Channels). You can change this with the `data_format` argument for a layer, but usually it is easier to change the data to channels last.
So your `input_shape` should be `(7, 7, 1)`.